# Echarts multicolored line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

Is it possible to make **echarts** line chart with 1 line painted in different colors? For example if value <= 0 the color is red, if > 0 the color is green?

Answer (score 1):

Echarts has an option called `visualMap` that does exactly what you are looking for.

- [visualMap doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise)
- [visualMap code example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-aqi) (I selected the example that fits best, but there are others)

In your case you'll have something like that :

```js
visualMap: {
   show: false, // Wether to show the legend or not (default: true)
   pieces: [
     {
       min: -9999, // Normally not needed but doesn't work without that (1)
       max: 0,
       color: '#F35E07' // Red
     },
     {
       min: 0,
       color: '#93CE07' // Green
     },
   ],
   outOfRange: {
     color: '#F35E07'
   }
},
```

It'll split your line in 2 pieces :

- below 0 (written `max: 0`) : red
- above 0 (written `min: 0`) : green

In addition, the `visualMap` option has more to offer : you can have more than 2 pieces (like in this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-aqi)), have a smooth gradient instead of pieces (using `type: 'continuous'` like in this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-gradient)), and many other things that are explained in its [doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise).

> (1) Note about the bug: Normally if you don't specify `min` or `max`,
> it's set to `-Infinity` or `Infinity`. But here you have to specify
> `min` AND `max` in one of the two pieces (I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider plotting two charts and ignoring some of its points with `'-'`, you can achieve the same visual result of a multicolored line chart.

---

Although the documentation does not provide an immediate example of how to color specific segments of a line chart, it actually instructs about how you can use [empty data](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/how-to/chart-types/line/basic-line#empty-data),

> While there are empty elements, the lines chart will ignore that point without passing through it----empty elements will not be connected by the points next. In ECharts, we use `'-'` to represent null data, It is applicable for data in other series.

With that in mind, by overlaying two equal charts and emptying some points, you can actually construct the logic of a multicolored chart. Notice that it is better if you can do it programmatically so that you can vary the number of line segments to be colored.

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

option = {
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        [-20, -20],
        [-10, 30],
        [0, 40],
        ['-', '-'],
        ['-', '-']
      ],
      type: 'line',
      lineStyle: {
        color: "red"
      }
    },
    {
      data: [
        ['-', '-'],
        ['-', '-'],
        [0, 40],
        [10, 100],
        [20, 60]
      ],
      type: 'line',
      lineStyle: {
        color: "green"
      }
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-heght: 100% !important }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.3.2/dist/echarts.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="main" style="width: 225px;height:225px;"></div>
</body>
```